# Randomly switch between View Controllers- Program crashes

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, xcode, ipad

I don't know much about programing but I still tried to do a program that e.g. you're in View Controller 1, press a button and it takes you to a randomly chosen View Controller, lets say View Controller 3 and in View Controller 3 you can press another button which takes you to another randomly chosen View Controller, lets say View Controller 2 and so on..

It works but I obviously did something wrong because the program crashes after 3 or less times that I press the button.

Here's the code of the action for the pressed button:

```
- (IBAction)next { 
// Get random value between 1 and 3
int y = (arc4random()%3)+1;

if (y == 1){
    [navigationController pushViewController:viewController animated:YES];
}
else if (y == 2){
    [navigationController pushViewController:viewController2 animated:YES];
}
else 
    [navigationController pushViewController:viewController3 animated:YES];
```

}

btw anything that has to do with "y" and the arc4random is ONLY used in this part.

Can someone tell me why it's crashing please? (I'm a beginner as I said before)
Thank you!

Comment: Please quote the crash-log-message and, if that is not conclusive the important part of the stack trace.

Comment: Can you please show your code, that initializes viewController/2/3 variables?

Comment: It seems likely you are not retaining your view controllers correctly

Comment: Can the same view controller be pushed onto the navigation controller multiple times?  (I don't know - someone must know though).

Comment: Yes it was because the view controller can't be pushed multiple times and the stack trace just said something about an exception (as explained below by another user) but I fixed it with help of that user and now it works, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Apple Documentation (http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UINavigationController_Class/Reference/Reference.html) said about `pushViewController`

> Important: In iOS 2.2 and later, if the object in the viewController
>   parameter is already on the navigation stack, this method throws an
>   exception. In earlier versions of iOS, the method simply does nothing.

This is the situation you are and you are trying to push the controller, which is already on the stack.

You are interested in the method

```
- (void)setViewControllers:(NSArray *)viewControllers animated:(BOOL)animated
```

Do this:

```
[navigationController setViewControllers:[NSArray arrayWithObject: ... ]];
```

Instead of `...` put your UIViewController

Comment: So I was right then... you cannot push a view controller into the same navigation controller more than once.

Answer (score 0):

I AM NOT SURE OF IT, BUT IT MAY BE THE REASON, PLEASE TRY ONCE:

May be, if you push a viewcontroller once, you can not push it again until you pop it, because it is already in stack. So you may need a little modification in code.

```
if (y == 1){
   if(isVC1Pushed == NO)

{

    [navigationController pushViewController:viewController animated:YES];
isVC1Pushed = YES
}
else{
[navigationController popToViewController:viewController animated:YES];
isVC1Pushed = NO;}

}
    }
```

Initialize the boolean as NO. Do the same for other view controllers also.

Comment: That was the reason but I tried it with another code and now it works, thanks anyways!!

Comment: I am sorry, I made a small logical mistake .. I hope that does not hurt , as you got the idea .. :)